# Deploying Django with gunicorn and buildout

Tags: python, django, deployment, buildout, gunicorn

I wrote a little Django app, using a websockets library (gevent-socketio) and building a virtual environment with buildout. Currently, for serving I have a custom command, that constructs the SocketIOServer class, just like [here](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server_integration.html#django-runserver) [1]. Doing it with gunicorn as it says in the docs isn't a difficult task.

So, I would like to use gunicorn as server, my question is about including gunicorn in the buildout.cfg, in order when gunicorn starts, it starts with all the modules existing in the virtualenv (PYTHONPATH).

Is there a recipe for gunicorn that can create a binary under ./bin/? I haven't found much information about buildout+gunicorn.

My buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout]
parts = django
newest = false
versions = versions
eggs = django 
         redis 
         gevent 
         gevent-websocket 
         gevent-socketio 
         greenlet 
         django-extensions 
         gunicorn

extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = *
sources-dir = external

[sources]
gevent = git git://github.com/gevent/gevent.git
gevent-websocket = hg https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-websocket
gevent-socketio = git git://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio.git
redis = git https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.git

[versions]
django = 1.4

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
settings = development
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = 
project = cacho_site
```

Thanks!

[1] http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server_integration.html#django-runserver

Comment: I see a [blog post](http://bluedynamics.com/articles/jens/repoze.bfg-gunicorn-zc.buildout) that sets up gunicorn in buildout, does that help?

Comment: the link to the blogpost does not work anymore.... but very interested in the solution, could you please add it as an answer here, and accept you own answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the buildout version 2.1.1 you can create a gunicorn script, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe/2.1.1

than you can simply bin/gunicorn and the rest of the arguments.